# Express.js route almost everything to one request

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I want to map all the requests that don't point to static files to my `index.html` and let javascript do the routing. But if I use the rules below all my requests (including the scripts and styles) hit the `*` rule.

```js
const express = require("express");

var app = express();

app.get("*", function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/index.html"));
});

app.use("/scripts/*", express.static("scripts"));
app.use("/styles/*", express.static("styles"));
app.use("/views/*", express.static("views"));

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Server is running, port: " + port);
});
```

I've also tried the reverse order.

Just to clarify here are some examples of what the expected behavior is:

- `/scripts/index.js` => `/scripts/index.js`
- `/views/app.html` => `/views/app.html`
- `/anything/here` => `/index.html`
- `/` => `/index.html`
- `/a/lot/of/stuff` => `/index.html`

I want to upload this to heroku and I don't want to use that many free credits. So I want to have all the routing and stuff on the JS to save up on computation on the server.

Comment: Have you tried to put the `app.get("*"...` route definition as the last one?

Comment: @tam.teixeira That's what I originally had and no it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use('/scripts', express.static('scripts'));
app.use('/styles', express.static('styles'));
app.use('/views', express.static('views'));

app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

Try to use the code in this manner and I really hope this will work for you

Comment: `/` does not work. I get `Cannot GET /test/` for a url like this: `/a/lot/of/stuff`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
Put all your files inside **public** folder (including index.html and other folders like script, styles, views)

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/')
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running, port: ${PORT}`)
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code will start working if you shift `app.use functions` to the top of your code

Comment: As stated in the comments, it doesn't work

Comment: '*' sign means for all, So your all requests goes to the same directory

Comment: Yes that's the problem and I'm asking what I should do to fix it

Comment: replace '*' with '/'

Comment: That doesn't match all the other requests though, just the home page

Comment: Turns out that was the problem (use and get order) but I also had a typo on the script url so it wasn't getting matched. It won't let me upvote unless you do a minor edit to your answer